# Unable to Symbolicate iOS App Crash Report

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, symbolicate

My app is occasionally crashing for some users and I have been unable to replicate the problem.

I have managed to get a few crash reports from one of the users which I have imported to Xcode, but I am unable to symbolicate the reports fully with some of the *myApp* lines not showing the actual class/code being called. Two sample stack traces extracts:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation          0x39e5c3e2 __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib         0x38eb595e objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation          0x39da66d0 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 160
3   CoreFoundation          0x39da6e04 +[NSArray arrayWithObject:] + 40
4   myApp                   0x0012117c 0x63000 + 778620
5   myApp                   0x0012c700 0x63000 + 825088
6   myApp                   0x00148784 0x63000 + 939908
7   myApp                   0x0013caf0 0x63000 + 891632
8   myApp                   0x0013b9da 0x63000 + 887258
9   myApp                   0x0006bda2 -[myAppAppDelegate init] (myAppAppDelegate.m:45)
10  UIKit                   0x3380d8aa -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 186
```

---

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation          0x39e5c3e2 __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib         0x38eb595e objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation          0x39da66d0 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 160
3   CoreFoundation          0x39da6e04 +[NSArray arrayWithObject:] + 40
4   myApp                   0x000c217c 0x4000 + 778620
5   myApp                   0x000cd700 0x4000 + 825088
6   myApp                   0x000e9784 0x4000 + 939908
7   myApp                   0x000ddaf0 0x4000 + 891632
8   myApp                   0x000dc9da 0x4000 + 887258
9   myApp                   0x0000cda2 -[myAppAppDelegate init] (myAppAppDelegate.m:45)
10  UIKit                   0x3380d8aa -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 186
```

This is an app submitted to the store from an archived build which still exists in Xcode. I have also tried the atos command, and running several of the symbolicate scripts available with no success. (I am 100% sure I have the correct .app and .dSYM files).

Anyone have any idea how I may be able to find out more info about these stack traces and determine where this crash is happening?

(Note: I am aware that line 9 references the app delegate's `init` command, which is very useful. My question is specifically regarding the subsequent calls that are not symbolicated)

Thanks!

Comment: check out [this][1],it will be helpful


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports

Comment: Thanks for the comment rehan. I have tried pretty much everything in that question with no luck before posting my question.

Comment: Without being able to answer the actual question, as a desperation move have you tried adding a breakpoint to `[NSArray arrayWithObject:]` (via Xcode's Add Symbolic Breakpoint...) then running your app to find all paths that end up in it with five levels of stack call separating where you are from `[myAppAppDelegate init]`? That'd probably give you less than a handful of suspects. Based on the trace, I'll wager you have something like `[NSArray arrayWithObject:obj]` where `obj` is `nil` under some circumstances.

Comment: Check out the answers of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242766/atos-and-dwarfdump-wont-symbolicate-my-address/10280230#10280230 You usually can't use the address directly any more. If atos using those hints won't help the corresponding code may not be present in the dSYM, e.g. by using a static library with stripped symbols.

Comment: Thanks Tommy and Kerni. Both useful comments. I'll investigate further tomorrow when I'm back in the office. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Well, I found the source of the problem in terms of my crash, but was still unable to symbolicate the report. I tried the suggestions on the link provided by Kerni which had some great info, but with no luck overall. So... whilst I don't *need* the answer to the question now as I have fixed my bug, I would still love to know how or why this report can't be symbolicated.

Comment: try to use this http://sourceforge.net/p/umsservices/wiki/Home/
if it can't solve the problem and you send me the crashlogs and the dSYMs I can try to symbolicate it for you (just to see where the tool linked failed)