# Reason for crash in iOS

Tags: ios

I got this crash from hockeyapp. I dont know what is the reason for this crash.

Please take a look into the crash and Please help if you can find the reason behind it.

Please take a look into thread 8 and thread 12..look like a race condition

```
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x3b1a5aa8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   CFNetwork                            0x2ff2186d CFURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequest + 266
2   Foundation                           0x30d0d523 +[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] + 112
3   SecureTextMessaging                  0x0040b30b -[EPOCWebServiceInvocation makeSynchronousRequestWithError:] + 148
4   SecureTextMessaging                  0x00346a0d -[CDSModule responseFromURL:] + 58
5   SecureTextMessaging                  0x000a5b65 -[STGetGroupsOperation responseForAction] (STGetGroupsOperation.m:37)
6   SecureTextMessaging                  0x0015ab0f -[STSyncOperation runOperation] (STSyncOperation.m:44)
7   SecureTextMessaging                  0x0015a7df -[STSyncOperation main] (STSyncOperation.m:24)
8   Foundation                           0x30caf5ab -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 768
9   Foundation                           0x30d5376d __NSOQSchedule_f + 58
10  libdispatch.dylib                    0x3b0e3f11 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 486
11  libdispatch.dylib                    0x3b0e3c97 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 40
12  libdispatch.dylib                    0x3b0e4a45 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 74
13  libdispatch.dylib                    0x3b0e4d29 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 54
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x3b21fbd3 _pthread_wqthread + 296
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x3b21fa98 start_wqthread + 6

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x3b1b8c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x3b21fa98 start_wqthread + 6

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x3b1b8c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x3b21fa98 start_wqthread + 6

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x3b1b8c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x3b21fa98 start_wqthread + 6

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x3b1a5aa8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   CFNetwork                            0x2ff2186d CFURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequest + 266
2   Foundation                           0x30d0d523 +[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] + 112
3   SecureTextMessaging                  0x0040b30b -[EPOCWebServiceInvocation makeSynchronousRequestWithError:] + 148
4   SecureTextMessaging                  0x00102c75 -[STLongPollingManager doClientPollwithMessageDate:andColleagueDate:error:] (STLongPollingManager.m:74)
5   SecureTextMessaging                  0x0001f691 -[STDataManager doClientPoll] (STDataManager.m:371)
6   SecureTextMessaging                  0x0001fde7 __29-[STDataManager doClientPoll]_block_invoke_2 (STDataManager.m:419)
7   Foundation                           0x30cbf3c7 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 128
8   Foundation                           0x30caf5ab -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 768
9   Foundation                           0x30d5376d __NSOQSchedule_f + 58
10  libdispatch.dylib                    0x3b0e3f11 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 486
11  libdispatch.dylib                    0x3b0e3c97 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 40
12  libdispatch.dylib                    0x3b0e4a45 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 74
13  libdispatch.dylib                    0x3b0e4d29 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 54
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x3b21fbd3 _pthread_wqthread + 296
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x3b21fa98 start_wqthread + 6
```

Comment: I didn't see where crash thread. please post full crash log or try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855389/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-xcode-6

Comment: The only problem with that approach would be if the device that has problem is remote and the developer can't access the phone

Comment: You should post the full crash report. None of the threads you posted yet show the one that actually caused the crash!

Answer (score 0):

At the first glance I would say that you have a problem inside

```
SecureTextMessaging
```

But there is a little that we could do to help you. I have several suggestions tho.

Try `dwarfdump` and `atos` commands. To use these you will need .ipa file you published. From there you have to extract/find .dSYM file.
So after you find that file you can try to look up particular addresses like :

```
SecureTextMessaging                  0x0040b30b -[EPOCWebServiceInvocation makeSynchronousRequestWithError:] + 148
```

In this example you can take 0x0040b30b. You need to know your architecture as well and after that you can try :

```
atos -arch armv7 -o STM.app/STM 0x0040b30b
```

To help you with addresses and everything else here is a very usefull SO question about that:

[iOS crash reports: atos not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574933/ios-crash-reports-atos-not-working-as-expected/13576028#13576028)

[atos and dwarfdump won't symbolicate my address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242766/atos-and-dwarfdump-wont-symbolicate-my-address)

On these links you will find everything you need to know and how to resolve your problem.